# New? Buttons on "Users" page behave differently than each other

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, users-page, responsive-design

I don't remember seeing these buttons before... I'm pretty sure the "Users" page used to look like the other tabs with the options being in a row with red underlines to highlight which tab is active on the page.

Now there are buttons but for some reason, the "reputation", "new users", and "moderators" all hover highlight in dark blue, making the text difficult to read while "voters" and "editors" don't.

[image: Gif showing odd behavior of buttons on "Users" page]

I'm guessing this is a fragment of the responsive design, as it does resemble the user pages on Stack Overflow. It's worth noting that this seems to have been rolled out to every site that I've checked, not only Meta Stack Exchange but the odd hover color only appears here (as far as I can tell).

---

So, I did some more poking around this morning and I realized that the reason that "reputation", "new users" and "moderators" have a different hover highlighting is because they're *visited*. Not quite sure how I missed this but it might help in determining how to fix it.

This is global across all sites with the buttons. Here's the page on M&TV:

[image: Movies & TV example of user page]

As you can see, I've tested this by clicking on the "editors" and "moderators" tabs, which have dark circles around them after being "visited" but the other three do not because I haven't clicked on them. "Editors" is darker grey because it's the tab that's currently active.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** I reverted the layout change. Tabs should be back to normal now.

---

So... earlier today I thought to myself "well, at least that rolled out without any issues". Apparently I was wrong. :)

I will look into this tomorrow, but the short version of the long story is that we're gearing up for rolling out responsive designs, left-side navigation, and "streamlined" theming to all sites in the network. The left nav bits went to production today (although not enabled anywhere) and as part of that, I tried to bring the Tags and Users list views in line with what they look like for Teams members on Stack Overflow currently.

Clearly I missed something in the styling, sorry about that. I don't have the code in front of me at the moment, so I'm not sure *what* that is. It didn't come up as an issue in testing... which is sort of half of an excuse. I checked the dev version of Stack Overflow and another site locally, but not the non-SO dev-tier sites we have up.

If I'm entirely honest, the fix here *might* have to wait a while. We're moving a lot of things around to support a much, much simpler setup going forward, and it's turning out to be more difficult than expected. But, this regression was certainly not intended and I will see what we can do. Either way, I do apologize, that's my bad.

P.S. Huh. That's weird. I don't see those hover colors either in the nav or on the "tabs" in the Tags/Users lists. I also don't see the weird underline thing on the tabs outside of here on MSE. Tomorrow sounds like it's going to be a lot of fun.

Comment: There's also a bug rendering the moderators tab, see https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog What's the bug? It seems fine here... Which, to be fair, apparently can't be trusted. :/

Comment: On IE11 with a viewport of 1920x1080, Tinkeringbell's link is shifted to the right.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Huh. Yeah, that's weird. I'm not 100% sure that's related to this change specifically... seems to be an issue on the last page of other tabs as well. But then again, it may well be. We'll look into it.

Comment: The bug @sonic said appears for all the site where there are 5 mods. Also reproduced for [scifi.se]

Comment: @Adam to be honest, it looks terrible on all sites, except SO. No offense meant, just my own personal view. I assume the design was done for SO, where it's indeed better than before, but when same style applied on other sites, it simply does not fit. Any chance to bring back the previous look on non-SO sites?

Comment: @Adam FYI the underline/shadow is there on Graphic Design too: [New look on /users page?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3475/52050)

Comment: Oh, they're the ones that are *visited*, which is probably why I don't have the bug on other sites... If I click on the two that weren't going dark on MSE, they turn dark after that... and clicking on them on other sites puts a dark circle around them but doesn't darken the background of the buttons.

Comment: I've edited the question to add more info. Looks like it's the visited styling, so if you can kill that part of the CSS it might just fix it?