# Looks like the design has changed on the Users page

Tags: support, design

Suddenly, the design of the /users page changed like this:

[image: Changed design of /users]

Other pages, such as /questions or /tags, haven't changed at all, which makes me think this might have been a premature or accidental change.

Was this change purposeful or not? Is it part of a network-wide design changing process?

Please note that this is most probably unrelated to [the new responsive design sneak peek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/225091), as the screenshot is from [Codegolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com). Also, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310878/225091) looks like a dupe at first, but this question focuses on reasoning, not a specific issue.

Comment: Looks like there's something related [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310878/225091), not sure if it's a dupe. The automatic search didn't find anything...

Comment: I believe it's purposeful for the ongoing network-wide responsive design project.

Comment: @SomewhatMemorableName Well, I guess we'll wait for an answer. :-) I'm not sure if it was supposed to come off on its own like that.

Comment: @Glorfindel Hm, are you sure? The screenshot is from Codegolf.SE, where there's no such thing as that yet.

Comment: It's part of the ongoing preparations.

Comment: @Glorfindel Well, also note that my question was asked ~3 hours before the sneak peek got announced over there. ;)

Comment: Adam's answer to my question implies it's intentional. :)